# Adding second sidebar for inner pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am customizing this Wordpress theme and I want it to have a similar 3-column homepage look as http://www.marieclaire.com/ especially the inner sidebar custom image title.

The theme I am using uses the same sidebar for all the pages and its not working with the custom image title, as it also appears on all pages. I want to add a second sidebar that only appears on all other pages except homepage.

I contacted the theme developer but they have not responded in 2 weeks and I am running against a set deadline. I need your help writing the code.

```
        <div class="primary-sidebar">
        <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-primary' ) ): ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-primary' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        $layout = get_theme_options_data( 'presto_website_layout' );
        if( ($layout != "layout-2") && ($layout != "layout-1") ):
        ?>
            <div class="secondary-sidebar">
            <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-secondary' ) ): ?>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-secondary' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .site-main-wrap -->
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very specific. Can you explain the problem in more detail? A live example might be useful too - perhaps publish what you have, so we can _see_ the problem. It's usually best, incidentally, not to impose your own deadlines on readers - volunteers on the web operate at their own leisure. If you need something urgently, you always have the option of engaging a freelancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this second sidebar something that is static, or something that you want to be able to add widgets to from the "Widgets" page?

If the first, just [create a separate page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for your inside pages and put your static sidebar in it.

If the second, you'll want to do the following:

1. Register a custom sidebar
2. Create a custom page template for your inside pages
3. Call the custom sidebar from your custom page template.

Here's a step-by-step guide for doing it:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-register-a-sidebar-in-wordpress